# Error handling in processing dates

Tags: error-handling, vb6

The code downloads CSV files from the server, cleans then up, and outputs the necessary data to an other CSV file.

My issue is, that on Sundays and holidays there are no files created on the server. So when such a date is encountered between the From and To date, the program stops going any further. How can this be avoided?

I want the program to go to next date if there is no file on the previous date.

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
(ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" _
(ByVal lpszUrlName As String) As Long

Private Const ERROR_SUCCESS As Long = 0
Private Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10
Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD As Long = &H80000000

Private Sub Command1_Click()
On Error GoTo Err
Const q As String = "-"
Dim tmp As String, fName As String, Pos As Long, fPath As String
Dim first As Date, last As Date, spath As String, d As Date
Dim sLineIn As String
Dim sLineOut As String
Dim sCols() As String
Dim sSymbol As String
Dim sName As String
Dim sDate As String
Dim sOpen As String
Dim sHigh As String
Dim sLow As String
Dim sClose As String
Dim sVolume As String
Dim sOpenIntrest As String
Dim sLastSymbol As String
Dim nCounter As String

cap = Me.Caption
If Dir(App.Path & "\NCDEX\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir App.Path & "\NCDEX\"
End If
spath = App.Path & "\NCDEX\" ' folder to save files : note trailing \
first = MonthView1
last = MonthView2
strURL = "http://www.ncdex.com/Downloads/Bhavcopy_Summary_File/Export_csv/"
For d = first To last
sSourceURL = strURL & Format(d, "MM") & q & Format(d, "dd") & q & Format(d, "yyyy") & ".csv"
Debug.Print sSourceURL
fName = Format(d, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".csv"
Debug.Print fName
slocalfile = spath & fName
Me.Caption = "Downloading " & fName
Call DeleteUrlCacheEntry(sSourceURL)
URLDownloadToFile 0&, sSourceURL, slocalfile, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0&

'  sLastSymbol = "zzz"  'Set to something Symbol cannot possibly be initially.
nCounter = 0
Open App.Path & "\temp.csv" For Output As #2
Open App.Path & "\NCDEX\" & fName For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, sLineIn
sLineIn = Replace(sLineIn, Chr(39), vbNullString)
      sLineIn = Replace(sLineIn, Chr(34), vbNullString)
      sLineIn = Replace(sLineIn, " ", vbNullString)
      sCols = Split(sLineIn, ",")
      sSymbol = sCols(0)
      sDate = sCols(15)
      sOpen = sCols(6)
      sHigh = sCols(7)
      sLow = sCols(8)
      sClose = sCols(9)
      sVolume = sCols(10)
      sOpenIntrest = sCols(14)

      If sSymbol = sLastSymbol Then
        nCounter = nCounter + 1
      Else
        nCounter = 1
      End If
      sLastSymbol = sSymbol

      Debug.Print sLineIn
      If sCols(10) <> "0" Then
  ' Only write lines that do not have "0" in Cols(12)

      sLineOut = sSymbol & "_" & nCounter & "," & sDate & "," & sOpen & "," & sHigh & "," & sLow & "," & sClose & "," & sVolume & "," & sOpenIntrest
      Print #2, sLineOut
      End If
    Loop
  Close #1
  Close #2

  ' Delete file 1 and rename file 2 as the original file 1 name.
  ' // Delete the original file
    Kill slocalfile
  ' // Rename the temp file to the original name
    Name App.Path & "\temp.csv" As slocalfile

Next
Me.Caption = cap
'YOU CAN TAKE THIS BELOW OUT IF U DONT WANT IT
MsgBox "Saved to " & spath, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Success!"
Exit Sub
Err:     MsgBox "Error", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Market Was Closed"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't looking a the return value of URLDownloadToFile(). If the file has started to download, it returns S_OK (=0). If "The specified resource or callback interface was invalid." then it returns INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE.

So you should do:

```
If URLDownloadToFile(0&, sSourceURL, slocalfile, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0&) = S_OK Then

    '  sLastSymbol = "zzz"  'Set to something Symbol cannot possibly be initially.
    nCounter = 0
    Open App.Path & "\temp.csv" For Output As #2
    Open App.Path & "\NCDEX\" & fName For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sLineIn
        sLineIn = Replace(sLineIn, Chr(39), vbNullString)
        sLineIn = Replace(sLineIn, Chr(34), vbNullString)
        sLineIn = Replace(sLineIn, " ", vbNullString)
        sCols = Split(sLineIn, ",")
        sSymbol = sCols(0)
        sDate = sCols(15)
        sOpen = sCols(6)
        sHigh = sCols(7)
        sLow = sCols(8)
        sClose = sCols(9)
        sVolume = sCols(10)
        sOpenIntrest = sCols(14)

        If sSymbol = sLastSymbol Then
            nCounter = nCounter + 1
        Else
            nCounter = 1
        End If

        sLastSymbol = sSymbol

        Debug.Print sLineIn
        If sCols(10) <> "0" Then
            ' Only write lines that do not have "0" in Cols(12)
            sLineOut = sSymbol & "_" & nCounter & "," & sDate & "," & sOpen & "," & sHigh & "," & sLow & "," & sClose & "," & sVolume & "," & sOpenIntrest
            Print #2, sLineOut
        End If
    Loop
    Close #1
    Close #2

    ' Delete file 1 and rename file 2 as the original file 1 name.
    ' // Delete the original file
    Kill slocalfile
    ' // Rename the temp file to the original name
    Name App.Path & "\temp.csv" As slocalfile
End If
```

I should also mention that looking at the documentation, it seems to imply that this function returns as the file is beginning to download. It may be that your file is so small that it has downloaded the entire file before the function returns. However, if you file got sufficiently bigger, it might still be downloading whilst your own code was executing, which would mean file access would fail, or worse, corrupt your data.

Have a look at the Remarks section in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: "if you file got sufficiently bigger, it might still be downloading whilst your own code was executing, which would mean file access would fail, or worse, corrupt your data."

Comment: Well, have a look at the MSDN documentation. They suggest that you implement a notification interface to determine how much of the file is being downloaded. You haven't done this. Try testing your code with a much bigger a file to see whether it is ok. If not, you wil have to handle that circumstance. Please report back on your observations.

Comment: Can you thank me with a vote up, please? Or make this the approved answer ? :-)